# How to fix error “The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect”?

Tags: python, windows, code-coverage, codecov

I use codecov in a python project on Windows, but when I try to upload coverage report to codecove server I get the following error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

```
D:\foo>codecov -t ***

      _____          _
     / ____|        | |
    | |     ___   __| | ___  ___ _____   __
    | |    / _ \ / _  |/ _ \/ __/ _ \ \ / /
    | |___| (_) | (_| |  __/ (_| (_) \ V /
     \_____\___/ \____|\___|\___\___/ \_/
                                    v2.0.15

[90m==>[0m Detecting CI provider
  -> Got branch from git/hg
  -> Got sha from git/hg
[90m==>[0m Preparing upload
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    Error running `cd 'D:\foo' && git ls-files`: None
[41mError:[0m[91m Missing repository upload token[0m

[42mTip:[0m[32m See all example repositories: https://github.com/codecov?query=example[0m
[92mSupport channels:[0m
  Email:   hello@codecov.io
  IRC:     #codecov
  Gitter:  https://gitter.im/codecov/support
  Twitter: @codecov
```

HOWEVER

If I run the `codecov` form WSL (Linux) (from the same repo, with the same reports), everything is fine.

---

**UPDATE**

codecov 2.0.10 can upload successfully, from 2.0.11 I get this *The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.* error.

Comment: Here is an appveyor example: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/raczben/wexpect/builds/30382641#L262

Comment: The single quotes around the path in `cd 'D:\foo'` are invalid syntax in CMD. It only supports double quotes for normal quoting. (Single quotes have a special use in a `for /f` loop statement.) CMD will end up trying to resolve the name relative to the working directory, e.g. `D:\foo\'D:\ `. I don't know why it doesn't end up as `D:\foo\'D:\foo'`, but in any case it isn't a valid file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the coverage report file (coverage.xml by default) using the `--file` switch. In this case codecov wont search for files and wont crash.

**`codecov --no-color -X gcov --file coverage.xml`**

(I suggest to disable coloring with `--no-color` and gcov `-X gcov`, to reduce unwanted errors.)

**UPDATE**

There is a fix for this issue:
https://github.com/codecov/codecov-python/issues/167